# Implementing OAuth2 with OpenAM for applications running on Nginx server

Tags: authentication, nginx, oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy, openam

I am trying to protect application behind nginx reverse proxy using OAuth2. I came across OpenAM and I am willing to use it. However, OpenAM web agent needs to be installed in the server where my apps are deployed. I am thinking of installing the web agent in nginx server.

Has anyone tried this before? There isn't any official nginx web agent for OpenAM. I just want to know pros-cons and if there are any other suitable alternatives for nginx/OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement OAuth2 for a web application, then a web agent is probably not the answer. Agents give a proprietary way to achieve single sign-on and policy enforcement for applications which are based on actual OpenAM sessions (i.e. cookie based SSO).

Since you want to implement OAuth2 you may want to look at [different technologies](https://github.com/3scale/nginx-oauth-templates/tree/master/oauth2/authorization-code-flow) instead, or simply just implement the protocol within the application itself.